# How do I disable stop word functionality in Solr when doing a phrase search?

Tags: solr, stop-words

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers have been satisfactory.

What I need to achieve is phrase searching in Solr without removing the stop words. In other words, an exact search.

There doesn't seem to be any way to turn off removing stop words at query time conditionally. One workaround is to have two fields: one where stop words are removed, and one where they aren't. But this isn't a solution, as it would require reindexing, and would need twice the disk space for the index.

Isn't it possible to make some kind of custom plug-in or something? My last resort is to remove the stop words conditionally at the source.

Comment: Your goal is to have the stop words in the index, but remove them from the given query when necessary? (and include them otherwise?) And in both cases, this should work against a phrase search?

Comment: A phrase query has to exactly match the index (after any processing). If the text has `I punch the bag with force` and you search for `"punch the bag"`, you will only find it if you enable stopword filtering on both index and query, or you disable it on both. If you index without stopwords, your index has `punch bag` and your query wants `punch the bag`; and vice versa. You could trick it by index without stopword filtering, and then at query time using proximity term instead of a phrase term when you want the other query (`"punch bag"~1`, if I remember correctly), but this is less than ideal.

Comment: @MatsLindh That is correct. I want stop words removed when doing a regular query, but not removed when doing a phrase search. The index does indeed contain the stop words, which is why I need them in the query for an exact match.

Comment: I think your only option in that case would be to remove them before sending them to Solr, yes - I'm not familiar with any option to create a different analysis chain under a field alias or something similar in the schema, so you'd probably have to do that yourself in that case.

Comment: Exact searches are tricky when you consider things like spaces ("hello world" vs " hello world" vs "hello world "), or punctuation ("hello" vs "hello!"), or case sensitivity ("Hello" vs "hello"). I think the two fields approach might be a good place to test to see if you get satisfactory results.

Comment: @MatsLindh My team lead found out there's a "stopwords" parameter for the (e)dismax query parser. Is there a reason it's not mentioned anywhere? Because it seems to do what I want.

Comment: It's documented here: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/edismax-query-parser.html#extended-dismax-parameters - seems like it should be exactly what you need!

Comment: @MatsLindh What I meant is that none of the other questions about this topic mention it. It must be relatively recent.

Comment: I think it was part of edismax when it was first added, about 12-13 years ago. :-) So probably just an oversight/not necessarily something that matches most people's use case. I didn't remember anything about it either.

Comment: In your schema.xml or managed-schema, check the datatype of your field. go to its definition which is also present in schema.xml only. copy that definition. give it another name and give that name to your field. remove the stopwordfilterfactory from it. reindex entire data and you are done.